# Sails js: service variable initialization

Tags: node.js, sails.js

The code below is just for reference. Assume my service name is `incremented` and it has the `incrementCounter` function

```
var counter = 0;
module.exports = {
    incrementCounter: function (req, callback) {
        counter++;
        callback(null, counter);
    }   
}
```

As you can see `var counter = 0` is defined outside the function so it is globally accessible inside all service functions. Now if i call the service twice in parallel it gives `1` for the first call which is correct but for the second call it is giving me `2`. Shouldn't the variable `counter` reinitialize itself with `0` when ever the service will be called?

```
incremented.incrementCounter(req, function(error, response){
 //response = 1
});

incremented.incrementCounter(req, function(error, response){
 //response = 2
});
```

Comment: Why do you need counter that does not increment itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sails initialize services only once: when you lift your application. It can be easily proven putting `console.log('service inits')` or something similar at the beginning of your service and see that it will be executed only once.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't the variable counter reinitialize itself with 0 when ever the service will be called?

No. `require()` in node caches the module, so subsequent requires aren't actually loading the file over and over. This is easy to test, just add a `console.log('hi')` at the top of your service.

You really should not define global variables like this *ever*, so this is more of a general node.js programming issue, and is not really sails.js related.